# How to plot values from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, weather

I have a dataframe, `test`, that contains winter temperatures since 1951 for a city. I want to plot the temperatures contained in the column called `wintermean` but when I try to do that using `plt.plot(test.wintermean.values)` I get the following error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>. Here's what `test`, `wintermean`, and `test.wintermean.values` looks like: [image] How can I plot this temperature data?

Comment: What do you get when you query the following? `test.wintermean.values[0]` and `type(test.wintermean.values[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your DataFrame has a single row and the column value is a `pandas.Series`. To plot that series, try:

```
test["wintermean"].iloc[0].plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clean up the data. there might be some non numerical values. For example "-" or "?". first convert those

```
 test['wintermean'] = pd.to_numeric(test['wintermean'], errors='coerce')
```

`errors='coerce'` will convert those non numerical values to `Nan` instead of throwing errors. then drop the `Nan` values

```
# drops Nan values in `winterman` column
test.dropna(subset=['wintermean'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Looks like each element of wintermean contains both the year and its corresponding temperature. `to_numeric` is likely not the appropriate solution here. The appropriate solution is likely fixing the data import.

Comment: he might set `index_col` while retrieving data